# I cannot get image to render after a network query

Tags: reactjs

Using Parse, I am querying the database and getting an imageURL back. React is not updating the dom.

componentWillMount and just regular curly brackets.

```
export const profileImage = async objectId => {
  const query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  query.equalTo("objectId", objectId);
  const image = await query.find();
  console.log(typeof image[0].attributes.image);
  console.log(image[0].attributes.image);

  return image[0].attributes.image; // return image;
}; // Query for a specific user and get image!
```

I imported it currently and it does the console logs so the function is executing but never rendering.

```
export default class MyDashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      profilePic: "",
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ profilePic: profileImage(window.localStorage.objectId) });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Sidebar />
        <div className={style.Componentcontainer} />
        <div className={style.main}>

        </div>
        <div className={style.profile}>
          <div> {this.state.profilePic} </div>
}
```

I eventually plan to put the string into an image tag, I just got to get this rendering first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your function is asynchronous, so `setState` will not wait and will render *undefined*.

To fix this, you should return a promise, and consume it with a `.then()` and set the state there instead. You should also use `window.localStorage.getItem()`, rather than trying to access a property immediately.

```
export const profileImage = objectId => {
  const query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  query.equalTo("objectId", objectId);
  return query.find();
};
```

```
export default class MyDashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      profilePic: ""
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    profileImage(window.localStorage.getItem(objectId)).then(image => {
      this.setState({ profilePic: image[0].attributes.image });
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Sidebar />
        <div className={style.Componentcontainer} />
        <div className={style.main} />
        <div className={style.profile}>
          <img src={this.state.profilePic} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If I helped please consider marking this answer solved. If you need anymore help, feel free to ask :)

Comment: Okay, I will. Thanks again

Comment: @04Tribe No problem :)